# How to Use Sql "Select" in Parse.com for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I checked parse.com s quide docs but i didnt understand clearly.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    if let objects = objects {
      for object in objects {
        print(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
  }
}
```

I will try to tell what i want to do with an example.  I want to
   describe an array and put entities in.

For example how can i put all elements of this query `select followers from user where userid = 123` in an array.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the way

```
 var query = PFQuery(className:"followers")


    query.whereKey("follower", equalTo:"fmv0N91zAf")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
    // Do something with the found objects
    for object in objects! {
        let following:String? = (object as! PFObject)["following"]as? String
        if following != nil{
        self.deneme.append(following!)
        }
    }
```